# deviceorientation doesn't work on any phone

Tags: javascript, angular

for some reason doesn't work, when I testing it via Sensor tool in browser, everything works, but on phone nothing happen.
Looks like is not triggered in phones
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dW3nL.png)

```
if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {  

      window.addEventListener(
        "deviceorientation",
        (event) => {
          const rotateDegrees = event.alpha; // alpha: rotation around z-axis
          const x = event.gamma; // gamma: left to right
          const y   = event.beta;// beta: front back motion        
    
     
      
      console.log("gyro is "+x,y)
      circle[0].style.top = height / 5  + y! / speed + 'px';
      circle[0].style.left = width / width +20 + x! / speed + 'px';    
  },
  true,
);

    }
```

Do you know where should be a problem ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScreenOrientation

Comment: I think you're listening to the wrong event to get gyro data. If you want gyro data you'll also need to request permission.

Comment: @epascarello but this is only for when I rotate phone from classic position to landscape-primary position  etc., I need gyro X + Y for smooth moving elements

Comment: @NickFelker and how looks like this permissions ? you need accept something on phone then?

Comment: If you want gyro then you'll have to use a different API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Gyroscope